# Studio Monitors/ Mac Mini (MINIJACK)

Tags: mac, connector, studio-monitors

I own a mac mini, which only has minijack for sound output from the computer to whatever sources you have. So, I bought 2 studio monitors and I am using RCA to  MINIJACK cables from each monitor. How do I route them together into 1 minijack connector and not lose any performance or gain on either monitor?

Comment: Typically you will lose some quality with every adapter. It's just a fact of life. Your best bet is going to be to get an external audio interface - this can then do impedance matching, gain etc., and ensure you get as high quality sound as you can.

Comment: Just get an RCA to stereo mini jack adapter.

Answer (score 2):

The mini-jack will be a stereo jack socket, which requires a TIP/RING/SLEEVE plug to interface correctly.

The two signals you will need are TIP/SLEEVE and RING/SLEEVE - with SLEEVE being the signal ground. You should be able to obtain a stereo minijack to RCA converter cable or plug adapter that will do this for you. The signal loss across this connection won't be noticeable.

Either get an appropriate adapter/connector from your local electronic retailer or you should be able to solder one up yourself.